# Getting AttributeError: __exit__ when working with Tensorflow and MNIST data

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm a beginner with Tensorflow and working with MNIST data. When trying to run a Tensorflow session as below, I'm getting Attribute error.

Could someone look into it?

The code snippet where I'm getting the error is below.

```
    with tf.Session as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for step in range(1000):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
            sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})

        # Evaluate the model
        matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_true,1))

        # Output will be like [True, False, True.....] --> Cast to [1.0, 0.0, 1.0.....]
        acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))

        print(sess.run(acc, feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images, y_true:mnist.test.labels}))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-c78b8b9359b3> in <module>()
----> 1 with tf.Session as sess:
      2     sess.run(init)
      3     for step in range(1000):
      4         batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
      5         sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})

AttributeError: __exit__
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `()` in order to create a new `Session` object/instance:

`with tf.Session() as sess:`

`tf.Session` just refers to the `Session` class.